# Optimize Mysql Configuration for deadlock error

Tags: magento-1.7, mysql

When i am trying to add product in Magento using Magento API. I am getting the following error:

`Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction`

I have read that this issue is because bad optimization of MySQL’s configuration for InnoDB.

My Mysql server configuration for InnoDB is as follows:

```
### INNODB_ #
innodb_thread_concurrency=8
innodb_lock_wait_timeout=100
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
innodb_log_files_in_group=2
innodb_log_file_size=64M
innodb_log_buffer_size=8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_buffer_pool_size=512M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=8M
```

Is anyone face the same error before? Is these configuration values are correct ? Please help.

Comment: The issue is always that multiple resources trying to modify the same data when data is locked. You can throw more power at this but the conflict will remain.

Comment: @AntonS .. How can I resolve this issue ?

Comment: by analysing it , we can't help you with that cause you have not provided enough information for this. So basically you need to search for a method how to analyse lock conditions and how to monitor this. this would reveal the conflicting parts.

Answer (score 1):

Try to truncate log tables

```
TRUNCATE `log_customer`;
TRUNCATE `log_quote`;
TRUNCATE `log_summary`;
TRUNCATE `log_summary_type`;
TRUNCATE `log_url`;
TRUNCATE `log_url_info`;
TRUNCATE `log_visitor`;
TRUNCATE `log_visitor_info`;
TRUNCATE `log_visitor_online` ;
```

I hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: @Bijal .. I have done this but problem still exist

Comment: @PankajPareek which magento version are you using?

Comment: Have you tried to do re-index? its just guess if it helps :)

Comment: Using Magento ver. 1.8.1.0

Comment: Is one of the indexers running whilst you attempt to import the product by any chance? This was the cause of most of our deadlocks.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the tables you can truncate.

```
TRUNCATE dataflow_batch_export;
TRUNCATE dataflow_batch_import;
TRUNCATE log_customer;
TRUNCATE log_quote;
TRUNCATE log_summary;
TRUNCATE log_summary_type;
TRUNCATE log_url;
TRUNCATE log_url_info;
TRUNCATE log_visitor;
TRUNCATE log_visitor_info;
TRUNCATE log_visitor_online;
TRUNCATE report_viewed_product_index;
TRUNCATE report_compared_product_index;
TRUNCATE report_event;
TRUNCATE index_event;
TRUNCATE catalog_compare_item;
```

Also try to truncate **catalog_url_rewrite** table then **re-index** for multiple time, it will really optimize the speed of your store, make sure you take backup of the database prior to optimization process.